# Spring data jpa complex request

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have entity

```
public class Event {
  private Long id;
  private String collectiveEventId;
...
```

repository for one and I need method to delete all elements if `collectiveId` is in range except element with `id`:

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
    void deleteByCollectiveEventIdInAndIdIsNot(Collection<String> collectiveEventIds, Long id);
}
```

I tried it, but all elements was deleted (element with specified Id - also).

I need help with valid method implementation `deleteByCollectiveEventIdInAndIdIsNot`?

Comment: `deleteByCollectiveEventIdInAndNotId` ?

Comment: What is the implementation you tried? Or do you just rely on the method name (in which case, you don't have any property named collectiveEventId in your entity). Why don't you just choose a better method name, and write a query?

Comment: Sorry, copied old property name - fixed. (with wrong property name context does not load.)

Comment: @Sergii what is your Spring Data JPA version? if your `Spring Data JPA  version <=1.6.x` it wont support query derivation for delete.

Comment: thanks, i'll use @Query than